# Accessing templatetags globally for django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I tried to add the path under INSTALLED_APPS and to create a folder of template tags and reuse them in multiple apps. But it is not working. Is there a smart way to work it out? All I need is to place templatetags for whole project in single directory accessible globally.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed your project layout and the changes you made to settings. You can use the [`libraries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) option in your `TEMPLATES` setting, but it's easiest to  follow the convention and add a `templatetags` directory to an installed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template tags need to be in an app.

But once they are, they can be used by templates in any app. There is no need to do anything to make them available globally.

Comment: You are right. I've tested it and its working. Its awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In your `settings.py` add:

```
AUTOLOAD_TEMPLATETAGS = (
'appname.folder.templatetags'
)
```

In the `urls.py` of your app, add:

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
from tag in settings.AUTOLOAD_TEMPLATETAGS:
    add_to_builtins(tag)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load templatetags %}
```

That should make them globally accessible.

Comment: @Alasdair I forgot to include the `urls.py` stuff. see revised answer.

Comment: This is using the old template settings before `TEMPLATES` was added in Django 1.8. [It won't work in Django 1.9](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/posts/importerror-cannot-import-name-add_to_builtins-under-django-19).

Comment: This didn't worked for me. As you mentioned that it is for old versions of Django. Still bundle of thanks for response.